# How can I simplify $\frac{\left (\sum x_{i} \right )}{\left ( \sum X_{i} \right ) \left (\sum x_{i}^2 \right )}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify
$$\frac{\left (\sum x_{i}  \right )}{\left ( \sum X_{i} \right ) \left (\sum x_{i}^2  \right )}$$

where $x_{i}=X_{i} - \bar{X}$ and $\bar{X}$ is the mean of all $X_{i}$'s

I thought of the following which, I must admit, looks wrong to me:
multiply the numerator and the denominator by $x_{i}$
$$\frac{\left (\sum x_{i} x_{i} \right )}{\left ( \sum X_{i} x_{i} \right ) \left (\sum x_{i}^2  \right )} = \frac{1}{\left (\sum X_{i}x_{i}  \right )}$$

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: Isn't the numerator zero ?

Comment: Right! sum of numbers in deviation... can't believe I didn't notice that! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just multiply by $x_i$ because in the summation is a "moving index", which means that $x_i$ represents actually many values (one value for each $i$), so in order to multiply by $x_i$ you'll have to fix a value for $i$, e.g. $i = i_0$ for which it's easy to see why $\sum_i {X_i x_{i_0}} \neq \sum_i x_i x_{i_0}$. That's why your approach seems wrong.

As @Paresseux Nguyen pointed out, the correct way to approach this is by noting that:

$$
\sum_i x_i = \sum_i X_i - \frac{n}{n} \sum_j X_j = 0
$$

I hope it helps :)